# Firebase crashlytics is not reporting anything on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I've initialized and configured Firebase for my Flutter project using [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) and the instructions given by the Firebase Console. After that, I followed [this crashlytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter) for adding crashlytics to my app. But no matter what I've tried, I couldn't see any reports on the Firebase console. Still seeing this;

[image]

My main function looks like this:

```dart
Future main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
      runApp(const App());
    },
    (error, stack) async {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack);
    },
  );
}
```

I've tried to;

- crash my app using `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash()`
- throw an exception and record it by the `onError` callback of the `runZonedGuarded`
- manually record an exception using `FirebaseCrashlytics.recordError(error, stack)`
- setting `fatal: true` or using `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError`

Is there something that I'm missing? I'm really stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you run this command before running the app : adb shell setprop log.tag.FirebaseCrashlytics DEBUG  as need  to check whats is logging to firebase  and please share the output of it here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter&authuser=0&hl=en check point 4

Comment: It says `E/FirebaseCrashlytics(21291): Cannot send reports. Timed out while fetching settings.`

Comment: can you please check that main mainfest file has internet permission or not ?

Comment: Yes, it has internet permission, I'm also sending requests to a rest api and works just fine.

Comment: Please download latest  google-services.json file and add to your project and try again by flutter clean

Comment: Are you using correct  dependecies for firebase crashlytics for android side gradle stuf ?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: Downloaded google-services.json from firebase console but its content was the same as the existing one. However, I tried `flutter clean` and restarted the app, now it works. Thank you so much for helping, now I understand that it's important to run `flutter clean` from time to time. :)